# What kind of transistors are prone to gate/base floatation?

Tags: transistors

What kind of transistors are prone to gate/base/etc flotation?

I know for sure that n-channel MOSFETs need a resistor connected to the ground to keep the gate low to obviate chances of flotations. But I don't know about other types of transistors like bjt, pnp, npn, jfet, etc.

I'd be thankful if you could give a list of transistors that need a resistor at gate/base/etc and a typical resistor value according to the trigger voltage. My main application is using Arduino's digital pins to control various types of transistors.

Sincerely,

Comment: Because your own research didn't work how? And where is it? This is not a "Oh, I don't know this, let's ask it in the broadest way possible"-service-station. We'll help, if you show actual effort into finding the answer ***yourself***

Comment: **Either** you're interested in electronics and would like to **understand** how certain transistors should be switched on/off from for example, an Arduino. Then **look around how it's done** and try to understand **why** it is done that way. **Or** you don't care about the **why** you just want to switch something, that's fine but then **look around how it's done** and do it that way but don't ask for a list for every device. Why would you need that anyway ? If you **understand** the **why** then you do not need a list.

Comment: And if you have a problem with above comments than say so here instead of downvoting / unaccepting my and Amyldof's comments and answers ! I mean, that is a bit childish itn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that all transistors (FET, BJT etc) need a leakage diverting resistor, connected control terminal to ground.

If your control circuit doesn't cause leakage under any conditions, then you don't need this resistor.

Some transistors don't need such a resistor, they already have it internally. Check the data sheet of each individual transistor to see which ones. Some FET types, some BJT types fall into this category.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am deeply grateful. The problem was that some schematics included them while other didn't. I learned it the hard way when I ordered a PCB and after soldering all parts I had random firing of N-Channel MOSFETs. It took a while to find out what was wrong with the circuit and it was due to exclusion of the resistor from gate to the ground. Now I want to use several JFETs and PNP transistors in another circuit and I was worried to have a similar situation.